# SharePoint foundation and BCS

Tags: bcs

I am testing  SharePoint 2010 foundation with bcs to access one of my sql tables.
I created a list with filters on some fields (wildcard and limit types)

But unfortunately, when I display (browser) the list no selection fields appear 
Do you know why?  Is it because of I'm using foundation?

Comment: what do you mean, "selection fields"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set default values on your wildcard filters.  When you set up filters on a BCS Read List operation, the list will show whatever the default value of the filters allow.

Do do this, when you are setting up the filter, you'll see a text box for "Default Value". Enter a value in there and update the ECT, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

are you getting any error messages? here is a post with some BCS related errors & fixes -
http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Part-2-BCS-Connectivity-Errors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

BCS works flawlessly on SharePoint foundation. I have imported an SQL Azure table as a external list and tested it for basic CRUD operations. Can you give more details about your error?